# UI Router parameters and Angular $http get call

Tags: angularjs, parameters

I'm trying to configure my search app (AngularJS and Elasticsearch) to display the user's search terms in the url on the results page after the search has been performed. Should that parameter be considered a query parameter or a url parameter? I'm using UI Router for my states and currently have it setup as a query parameter as you can see below. However, with the current setup, it breaks search.

So 1), should it be a url parameter?
2) How to correctly configure my `search()` to include params in my Angular `$http get` call so that search works?

For my states (ui router)

```
.state('home', {
        url: '/',
```

Where user enters search terms, then

```
.state('search', {
        url: '/search?q',
```

where results are displayed and more searches can be performed

For search() in my controller

```
//for query parameters
var config = {
  params: {
    q: vm.searchTerms
  }
};

//search()
vm.search = function() {
  $state.go('search', {q: vm.searchTerms});
  console.log(vm.searchTerms);
  console.log('success - search');
  vm.currentPage = 1;
  vm.results.documents = [];
  vm.isSearching = true;
  return coreService.search(vm.searchTerms, vm.currentPage, config 
  )
  .then(function(es_return) { 
    console.log('success - return');
    var totalItems = es_return.hits.total;
    var totalTime = es_return.took;
    var numPages = Math.ceil(es_return.hits.total / vm.itemsPerPage);
    vm.results.pagination = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      console.log('success - for');
      vm.results.totalItems = totalItems;
      vm.results.queryTime = totalTime;
      vm.results.pagination = coreService.formatResults(es_return.hits.hits);
      vm.results.documents = vm.results.pagination.slice(vm.currentPage, vm.itemsPerPage);
      console.log('success - documents');
    }
        vm.noResults = true;
      }),
    function(error){
      console.log('ERROR: ', error.message);
      vm.isSearching = false;
    },
    vm.captureQuery();
    console.log('success - captureQuery');
};
```

The query parameter is in the url, but search doesn't breaks.

**UPDATE**
More details. You enter your query on the homepage, ('home') state and then once you submit your query, I use $state.go to transition to the ('search') state, which is the results page. The home page and results page do use 2 different templates for their views. So I do have 2 search boxes - 1 on the home page and the 1 on the results page.

The search terms are displaying in the url whether I start from 'home' state or enter the query on the 'search' state. All that is breaking is the search functionality - which WAS working before I tried implementing the parameter in the url.

Also I init vm.searchTerms like this

```
vm.searchTerms = $stateParams.q || '';
```

Not sure if that makes a difference or is causing the problem?

Comment: Can you please post complete functions at least. Some source seems missing.

Comment: @Thomas, that is my entire search function with config object right above it.

Comment: @Thomas, I think I deleted your last comment by accident, the search() is in my searchController

Comment: Could you clarify the behavior of the states ? e.g. Do you have a searchbox in some other than `search.html` template and after submitting the query you redirect user to a `results.html` template ?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is after submitting the search query to redirect user to a `search.html` template, having passed the query in `$state.params` url. Then in `SearchController` I would perform the `search()` if there are any params. This way even after user refreshes the page the params will still be on the url and a new `search()` will be called and there will or won't be results after communicating with the API.